# How can I "highlight" this CSS button when is clicked using CSS3 or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

into an HTML page I have 2 buttons implemented by something like this:

```
<!-- Bottone relativo ai progetti WIFI: -->
<a title="WIFI" href="javascript: void(0)" id="showWifi_${item.index}" class="showWifi">
    <div class="news_box news_box_01 hvr-underline-from-center " style="margin-right: 50px;"></div>
</a>

<!-- Bottone relativo ai progetti PNSD: -->
<a title="PNSDe" href="javascript: void(0)" id="showPnsd_${item.index}" class="showPnsd">
    <div class="news_box news_box_02 hvr-underline-from-center "></div>
</a>
```

And this is the related CSS that show a background immage to the div implementing the button:

```
.news_box_01 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../../img/icons/projects/wifi_big_transparent_2.png") repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.news_box_02 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../../img/icons/projects/PNSD.png") repeat scroll 0 0;  
}
```

Ok, now my problem is that I have to highlight the selected button when the user click on it.

I know that I can use the **:active** selector to select a clicked link. The problem is that I don't know how can I use CSS to "hightlight" (or implement some other CSS 3 effect) on the backround immage when the link is clicked

Do you have some idea?

Comment: Hope you're looking some new ideas, as described [**here**](http://goo.gl/aELwk)

Comment: Use e.g `a:active > div` as rule. Is that your question???

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctely, you want to apply changes for after a click.

```
$(".showWifi").on("mousedown", function() { 
    //fires when the mouse is press down
    //using "click" instead of "mousedown" means the mousebutton 
    //must be pressed down then up before the function fires.

    $(this).addClass("highLightButton");

})
```

don't hesitate to ask for further explanation or help

Comment: Tnx but my main problem is how to set a style that change the style of the clicked button (the CSS code of the highLightButton class)

Comment: You would write the ".highLightButton" class with wanted CSS in your stylesheet. If that's not what you mean then I think you need to alter your phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

use :active for anchor elements

```
a:active {/*styles here*/}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYYGLG

Answer (score 0):

Use `:active` selector in your css:

```
a:active .news-box{
/*
Some magic code to make a nice background!
*/
}
```

so whenever your `a` is active, the css above will be applied to the `.news-box` child of that `a`.

## Edit:

Your magic code can be something like this:

```css
a{
  width:100px;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#fff;
  }
.news-box{
  
  padding:10px;
  background-color: #21B4C3;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 25%,transparent 25%,transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%,transparent 75%,transparent);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 25%,transparent 25%,transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%,transparent 75%,transparent);
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 25%,transparent 25%,transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%,transparent 75%,transparent);
-webkit-background-size: 40px 40px;
background-size: 40px 40px;
}
a:active .news-box{
 -webkit-animation: magicbg .92s infinite;
  -moz-animation: magicbg .92s infinite;
  -o-animation: magicbg .92s infinite;
  animation: magicbg .92s infinite;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes magicbg {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes magicbg {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes magicbg {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
@-keyframes magicbg {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
<div class="news-box">Button1</div>
</a>
<a href="#">
<div class="news-box">Button1</div>
</a>
```

Comment: ehhh my problem is the "magic code" for the background (withoud using a new image)

Comment: Then we need to know what effect exactly you want to apply. like:fading out the image and displaying a text on it?

Comment: @AndreaNobili added a sample to the answer but it's almost impossible to help you without knowing what sort of change do you want on the background.